# How can I fix my face?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

```
I FOUND SOME PILLS, AND I ATE THEM!
```

[image: Derrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr]

---

**...**

That's cool and all, but how do I get out of this state?  It's not good with the ladies.

Comment: To note: The Flies are separate items.

Comment: Pretty sexy if you ask me.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot - I know this guy you should meet...

Comment: btw, do these pills actually change anything besides appearance?

Comment: @BruceConnor nope, it's only a superficial change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As duly noted, the only way to fix your face is to pick up another item which changes your face. Many items have nothing to do with your face, such as those that give you a "hat" (*Cupid's Arrow*), overlay (*Wooden spoon*) or something else entirely (*Battery*).

Here is a list of items that change your face (with caveats where appropriate. If you need to know how any of these look, [check the wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items)):

- Charm of the Vampire
- The Pact
- Growth Hormones
- The Inner Eye
- Max's Head
- Money = Power (Gives dollar-signed glasses, but may not reset your face)
- Mr. Mega
- Number One
- Roid Rage
- The Sad Onion
- Wiggle Worm
- The Common Cold

Of course, I have to admit I haven't had a chance to pick up each and every item yet (though I'm pretty close). I also left out *Mom's Lipstick*, which I am pretty sure will not help in this case. I've also left out *The Virus*, as I seem to recall cases where it only affected my body (though that may have been a result of me picking it up first, then changing my face).

Answer (score 5):

Keep on exploring; soon enough you'll find a new item or pill that will conflict with and replace this facial feature.

Comment: To clarify - almost every item changes your appearance.  The only way to change your appearance is with items.  So, basically, you're stuck unless you get lucky and can erase it (a lot of features just stack, though).